# Opengles fragment shader achieve the effect

Tags: ios, xcode, opengl-es

I want to achieve a smooth merge effect of the image on center cut. The centre cut i achieved from the below code.

```
varying highp vec2 textureCoordinate;
uniform sampler2D videoFrame;

void main(){
    vec4 CurrentColor = vec4(0.0);

    if(textureCoordinate.y < 0.5){
         CurrentColor = texture2D(videoFrame,vec2(textureCoordinate.x,(textureCoordinate.y-0.125)));     
    } else{
         CurrentColor = texture2D(videoFrame,vec2(textureCoordinate.x,(textureCoordinate.y+0.125))); 
    }

    gl_fragColor = CurrentColor;    
}
```

The above code gives the effect to below image.

Actual:

[image: Actual]

Centre cut:

[image: Centre cut]

Desired Output:

[image: Desired output]

What i want is the sharp cut should not be there, there should be smooth gradient merge of both halves.

Comment: Could you please do a photoshop to showcase the desired outcome?

Comment: @datenwolf this is the desired output. [link](http://i.imgur.com/XRKUf.jpg)

Comment: datenwolf is dealing well with the actual question; my only comment is that you'd likely see better performance with two varyings that represent the two possible sampling coordinates rather than one that you dynamically modify. Counterintuitively, it may even be faster to do both samples unconditionally and then pick a colour (but you'd need to profile — see Page 87 of https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/3DDrawing/Conceptual/OpenGLES_ProgrammingGuide/OpenGLES_ProgrammingGuide.pdf )

Comment: Tommy has a good point here. Any calculation involving a texture coordinate seems to trigger a dependent texture read, which really slows things down on the iOS device GPUs. If you can calculate that offset in the vertex shader and pass it in, you'll probably see much better performance, especially with the removal of the branching in favor of the smoothstep() function.

Comment: While Tommy has a point, but at this point of time, I am not really worried about the performance, as even this is fine with me.

Answer (score 2):

Do you want an actual blur there, or just linear blend? Because blurring involves a blurring kernel, whereas a blend would be simple interpolation between those two, depending on the y-coordinate.

This is the code for a linear blend.

```
varying highp vec2 textureCoordinate;
uniform sampler2D videoFrame;

void main(){
    float steepness = 20; /* controls the width of the blending zone, larger values => shaper gradient */
    vec4 a = texture2D(videoFrame,vec2(textureCoordinate.x,(textureCoordinate.y-0.125)));     
    vec4 b = texture2D(videoFrame,vec2(textureCoordinate.x,(textureCoordinate.y+0.125)));

    /* EDIT: Added a clamp to the smoothstep parameter -- should not be neccessary  though */
    vec4 final = smoothstep(a, b, clamp((y-0.5)*steepness, 0., 1.)); /* there's also mix instead of smoothstep, try both */

    gl_FragColor = final;    
}
```

Doing an actual blur is a bit more complicated, as you've to apply that blurring kernel. Basically it involves two nested loops, iterating over the neighbouring texels and summing them up according to some distribution (most flexible by supplying that distribution through an additional texture which also allowed to add some bokeh).

Comment: Hi @datenwolf, The above doesn't help me achieve the desired effect. What it does is its doing the smooth step of entire pixels, But as per what I want is only in the centre.

Comment: To clarify my need further, What i am trying to do is, to cut the centre part of the image (say 20 pixels) and and than join the other 2 halfs with a smooth gradient merge. Hope this helps you in understanding my need and helping me further.

Comment: @Manish: That's what the parameter steepness is for. Increase that parameter to your desire, the larger the value, the smaller the interpolation region. Better make it a uniform to be able to adjust it as a parameter.

Comment: I understand the use of steepness, but than below are the samples i have took from the above code, there is replication on all the pixels.

Comment: Here is the sample screenshot i took from the above code. [actual](http://i.imgur.com/xXnq2.jpg) and [after applying filter](http://i.imgur.com/r3X7E.png). Also you can see there is color burn effect coming.

Comment: @Manish: The color "burning" indicates, that values are getting overstaturated, which should be happening. I think we've found a bug in your GLSL implementation. See my updated code for a version that fixes your issue.

Comment: I think this is fine now. I am near to achieve it. But was wondering if i have to blur a little bit, than how would i achieve it.

Comment: @Manish: You'd have to apply some blurring convolution kernel to both of the images, maybe making the blurring strength dependent on the distance from the transition, and then apply that transistion blending onto the pre-blurred images. Google for GLSL blurring to get the idea how to do blurring.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I have achieved blur also. Though its a bit slow, due to multiple sampling, But i can workaround on that.